# how to split a string or make chars in vb 2010

Tags: string, split, chars

I searched but nothing explains how to do this,
for example

```
Dim sentence as String = "cat is an animal"
```

if i make a msgbox :

```
MsgBox(sentence)
```

it shows

```
cat is an animal
```

how to make a msgbox that says

```
cat
is
an
animal.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way Replace space with new line

as in string words = `MyString.Replace(" ","\r\n")`

Split would be split on space in to an array , and then join that back up with new lines which is pointless unless you need the array for something else.

Comment: I got the code :
    Dim sentence2 As String = "cat is an animal"
    Dim sentence = sentence2.Replace(" ", vbNewLine)
    MsgBox(sentence)

Comment: Well there you go, you learnt something. Satisfying isn't it? Much more so than someone just giving you AN answer. I can think of loads of ways of doing what you asked, mainly because I got off my arse and learnt them. "Just gimme the code", sheesh